# How to run this page just once after installing the page

Tags: java, android

I want this code to run just once after installing the app. 
Page 1 has a button and after clicking it, the user will be directed to page 2. 
Page 2 is the disclaimer page and after checkboxes are marked and agree button is clicked, the user is directed to the home page.
When the user clicks for the second time, this disclaimer page should not open again.
I tried to modify my code for it, but I couldn't because of the button as I'm not sure how to use it.

Page 1

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button btn_Shap;

    public void first(){

        btn_Shap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Shap);
        btn_Shap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent btn = new Intent(MainActivity.this, disclaimer.class);

                startActivity(btn);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        first();

    }
}
```

Page 2

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class disclaimer extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button button2;
    public Button button1;


    public void second(){

        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent btn = new Intent(disclaimer.this, home.class);

                startActivity(btn);
            }
        });
    }

    public void first(){

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent btn = new Intent(disclaimer.this, MainActivity.class);

                startActivity(btn);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_disclaimer);

        second();
        first();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the desclaimer page store a boolean value using shared preference and check it before open the desclaimer page. like this

**Inside the Desclaimer page**

```
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
         editor.commit();
```

**Before open the desclaimer page**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);
    if ( firstRun )
    {
     //Open desclaimer
    }else{
//Do not open desclaimer
}
```

Comment: if my solution worked then please upvote the answer.

Comment: I did, but it won't appear since my reputation is less than 15. Sorry :(